# CSS styling of scrollbar when actively scrolling

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

**Background:** I'm using MUI and attempting to customize the site-wide scrollbars via the [theme](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/). A pure CSS solution would also be acceptable.

**Goal:** I'm trying to apply certain styles to the scrollbar while it's actively being used to scroll - even if the user isn't currently hovering over the scrollbar. For instance, if the mouse is in the middle of the page and is scrolling, these styles should apply to the scrollbar. The notable issue here is that the styles to be applied to the scrollbar while it's actively scrolling are the same as the styles applied to it while hovering, but different from the styles applied to it when it's not being used/hovered.

**Issue:** I can't get any styles to apply to the scrollbar while it's being scrolled, unless I'm hovering over it or have pressed-and-held it to scroll. I'm able to customize the scrollbar and also the styles applied to it when hovering over it. I thought I could use the [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) pseudo-class to achieve my goal, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
const theme = useMemo(() =>
{
    return createTheme(
    {
        components:
        {
            MuiCssBaseline:
            {
                styleOverrides:
                {
                    body:
                    {
                        '&::-webkit-scrollbar, & *::-webkit-scrollbar':
                        {
                            // Style-A goes here. Works as expected.
                        },

                        '&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active, & *::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active':
                        {
                            // Style-B goes here. No effect.
                        },

                        '&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover, & *::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover':
                        {
                           // Style-B goes here. Works as expected.
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    })
}, [])
```

Here's the CSS version of the above code, that yields the same results:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    /** Style-A goes here. Works as expected. */
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active
{
    /** Style-B goes here. No effect. */
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover
{
    /** Style-B goes here. Works as expected. */
}
```

I'm using [`createTheme`](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#createtheme-options-args-theme) to apply these styles site-wide, but the same code above used in a global CSS file has the same issues.

Any solution using the above MUI methods, or similar methods in pure CSS will work.

I'm open to hearing about JS-based solutions that work in React, but I'd rather find a way to make it work (if possible) with my current approach since everything works as expected except this one wrinkle.